# Map reduce example beside word count

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I followed step by step via example in here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_mapreduce.htm

I want to find max of each year in file like the following:

```
1320 23
1221 60
1320 33
1221 66
```

And the result that I expected is:

```
1320 33
1221 66
```

And I did like the following in java:

```
import java.util.*; 

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.IOException; 

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*; 

public class ProcessUnits {
   //Mapper class 
   public static class E_EMapper extends MapReduceBase implements 
   Mapper<LongWritable ,/*Input key Type */ 
   Text,                /*Input value Type*/ 
   Text,                /*Output key Type*/ 
   IntWritable>        /*Output value Type*/ 
   {
      //Map function 
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,   
      
      Reporter reporter) throws IOException { 
         String line = value.toString(); 
         String lasttoken = null; 
         StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line," "); 
         String year = s.nextToken(); 
         
         while(s.hasMoreTokens()) {
            lasttoken = s.nextToken();
         }
         int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken); 
         output.collect(new Text(year), new IntWritable(avgprice)); 
      } 
   }
   
   //Reducer class 
   public static class E_EReduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer< Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > {
   
      //Reduce function 
      public void reduce( Text key, Iterator <IntWritable> values, 
      OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException { 
         int maxavg = 0 ; 
         int val = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            
         while (values.hasNext()) { 
            val = values.next().get();
            if(val > maxavg) { 
                maxavg = val ;
                
            }
             
         }
         output.collect(key, new IntWritable(maxavg));
      } 
   }

   //Main function 
   public static void main(String args[])throws Exception { 
      JobConf conf = new JobConf(ProcessUnits.class); 
      
      conf.setJobName("max_eletricityunits"); 
      conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 
      conf.setMapperClass(E_EMapper.class); 
      conf.setCombinerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setReducerClass(E_EReduce.class); 
      conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class); 
      conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class); 
      
      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0])); 
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1])); 
      
      JobClient.runJob(conf); 
   } 
}
```

The error I got when I execute this program is the following:

> Error: java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at ProcessUnits$E_EMapper.map(ProcessUnits.java:28)
    at ProcessUnits$E_EMapper.map(ProcessUnits.java:14)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:465)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)
```

I know this problem is because my program can't maps line by line of file  , it maps entire file

```
    String line = value.toString(); 
    String lasttoken = null; 
    StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(line," "); 
    String year = s.nextToken(); 
             
    while(s.hasMoreTokens()) {
       lasttoken = s.nextToken();
         }
    int avgprice = Integer.parseInt(lasttoken); 
    output.collect(new Text(year), new IntWritable(avgprice));
```

Any idea to solve this problem from you guys?

Comment: Which line is 28 in your example? If it is `String year = s.nextToken();`, then you are attempting to get a token that does not exist. This is probably due to empty lines in your input file? If you encounter an empty line, then you have zero tokens, and thus can't read the year - or even read anything.

Comment: Yes, don't overcomplicate something so simple. All you have to do is use a Map Collection. Use the year as an Integer key. The either `.put()` or `.replace()` the highest value. I realize that doesn't really address your tutorial issue.

Comment: @TreffnonX exactly , it map whole file  not each line of text .How to make map function for each line of text

Comment: @RandyCasburn my purpose is how to make map function for each line of text not whole text. so help me

Comment: This: https://replit.com/@randycasburn/scratch-java#Main.java shows the data you provided in a variable, but the scanner could read it from a file just as easily.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Your code solves OPs problem, but does not use hadoop. I think the point is to make it work within the framework.

Comment: @TreffnonX so any idea for me

Comment: @TreffnonX - I acknowledged that in my first comment, but the entire mapper function that solves the OP's problem is in the `if` statement I provided.

Comment: @Dunguyen Are you absolutely sure you are reading the entire file at once? I think it might not be the case. If the framework works correctly, and you did everything as described in the tutorial, it should work. However you might have empty lines in your input file. To prevent this, just return, if the input text is empty. As an alternative, just remove any empty lines from your input. And don't have a linebreak at the end of the file!

Answer (score 0):

Try reading each line from file once and split the values. Map all the corresponding years and prices. Then using reduce function compare the price with some constant if greater assign the value.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class E_Mapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
public void map(LongWritable ikey, Text ivalue, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    
    String line= ivalue.toString();
    String [] values = line.splitBy(" ");
    for(String price:values)
    {
        context.write(new Text(year),price);          
}}}


public class E_Reducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int avg=0;
    for (IntWritable val : values) {
                   if(val.get()>avg){
             context.write(key,new IntWritable(sum));
}}}
```